# re.sub() error related to MatchObject.group()

Tags: python, regex

I have a very simple job for `re.sub()`, but am not able to get it to work correctly.

```
import re
print re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x:x, "1 2 3 4 5")
```

The matched strings should be printed as-is, so the expected output is:

```
1 2 3 4 5
```

The error I am getting is :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "_.py", line 2, in <module>
    print re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x:x, "1 2 3 4 5")
  File "/home/radar/anaconda/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 155, in sub
    return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, _sre.SRE_Match found
```

Comment: You should probably have read [the manual](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)...

Comment: Sure. But the power discussions in the comments are enticing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The replacement function is passed a [*match object*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects) by `re.sub()`. You return that match object directly, while you must return a string instead; after all that is what is going to be used to replace (*sub*stitute) the original match.

You could return the matched text, via the [`MatchObject.group()` method](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.group):

```
print re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: x.group(), "1 2 3 4 5")
```

You have not clearly stated you expected to happen, however; the above will return the original string, as it replaces each digit with itself:

```
>>> re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: x.group(), "1 2 3 4 5")
'1 2 3 4 5'
```

or you could increment the number by one (which requires conversion to an integer, then after manipulation, conversion back to a string):

```
>>> re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: str(int(x.group()) + 1), "1 2 3 4 5")
'2 3 4 5 6'
```

Comment: Isn't this the way it normally works, you print the match. eg : `print re.findall(r"\d+", "1 2 3 4 5")` works fine.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: `re.findall()` doesn't do replacements, `re.sub()` does, and you used a function to produce the replacement. What did you want to achieve here by using `re.sub()`?

Comment: I wished to print the square of the numbers in the list. 
I can do that now with : `print re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: str(int(x.group())**2), "1 2 3 4 5")`.

Comment: I noticed that I need to typecast to `str` in the `lambda`. Why won't `print re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: int(x.group())**2, "1 2 3 4 5")` work ?

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: because the second argument, if it is a function, **must** return a string.

Comment: So, the function/lambda in `re.sub()` must always return a `str` ?! Seems restrictive.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary well you're trying to interpolate it back into a string and Python is strongly typed, so that *"restriction"* makes sense. Additionally, this is the **documented behaviour**: [If *repl* is a function, it is called for every non-overlapping occurrence of *pattern*. The function takes a single match object argument, and returns the replacement string.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub)

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: you *are* manipulating strings here. Regular expressions only work on strings, so it is only logical that you need to return back a string too.

Comment: @DarshanChaudhary: and as the Zen of Python states: *explicit is better than implicit*; by requiring that you return a string you more easily can catch bugs in your replacement function. If you forget to add a `return` somewhere, but another branch of the function returns the string `'None'`, how will you know the difference?

Comment: A minor doubt : I am trying to match all ` && ` characters in a str (space+`&&`+space). However, I am not getting the second one. My string : `c $&1|| || &&` **`&&`** `&|&&| & | | &&c `

Answer (score 1):

```
re.sub(r"\d+", lambda x: x.group(), "1 2 3 4 5")
```

Comment: Although this fixes the OP's problems, it would be helpful to explain *how* it does so. What precisely have you changed, and why?

Comment: @jonrsharpe: Martijn Pieters is giving better explanation from me.

Comment: This is true, but doesn't exempt you from making your own answer better!